# Layout And Views Visibility on app

Tags: java, android, listview, layout

I was testing my android app on device by enabling device show layout boundaries in developer option on device.
I check my listview with inflated view with textviews , rating bar and other views clearly seen as shown below . [image]

later I tried twitter app but surprise to see only single view ???

[image]

anyone know how to get twitter like single view on listview ??

Answer (score 3):

> anyone know how to get twitter like single view on listview ??

Each list item is a single custom `View` object, not a `ViewGroup` or layout.  Essentially, all the content is drawn directly onto the `Canvas` in `onDraw()` rather than relying on child `ImageView` and `TextView` elements.  Images can be drawn easily enough by calling `Drawable.draw()` or `Canvas.drawBitmap()` and text is typically drawing using a `Layout`.

Additionally, this means all touch events are handled directly inside `onTouchEvent()` to handle taps on the lower icons and/or the avatar image, so there are no click listeners.

**Edit:** Here's a quick 30 second example that should be enough to get you started: https://gist.github.com/devunwired/8704007

[image]

Comment: u know plenty of things , please share sample code or way to do it properly .

Comment: Which one consume memory more or performance issue ?? Please write on your blog about this in depth .

Comment: Perhaps I will someday in the future.  In general, fewer views in your hierarchy is always better for both memory and performance.  Fewer objects in memory and less time spent in measurement/layout code.

Answer (score -1):

They are probably using the include tag to include another layout file

you can do the same thing if you make your list_row_item layout something like this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:layout_width=”match_parent”
    android:layout_height=”match_parent”
    >

    <include layout="@layout/another_layout"/>


</LinearLayout>
```

The benefit to doing this is that you can swap layouts on the fly, perhaps even using a server side changes, rather than having to issue a software update

Comment: Any Samples or examples how it deal with server side changes ??

Comment: this is wrong; "show layout boundaries" doesn't care how the views get inflated. devunwired has it right.